# Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug in Processing

Tags: java, android, debugging, processing

I am using Processing to code and have been stuck on a problem for hours now, and after many hours of debugging I have given up because I need help. The error reads:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\ >
>   myUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\android5429541723127013969sketch\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\1.jar

**What I have tried:**

What was recommended most was using

> ./gradelw clean

However this meant a whole bunch of new problems with the command still not working and getting stuck on

> ```
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener error
> ```

Which I have not found a solution for.

Deleting the Android folder did not seem to resolve the issue, with it persisting and not making a new android folder

Reinstalling the Android Library which did also not resolve the problem

crossPosted at https://discourse.processing.org/t/execution-failed-for-task-app/24563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem quite a while ago. One of the reasons can be that the libraries that you may be importing in your processing sketch is not supported on android.
Try removing the import statements to find out which may be causing the error.

If all the libraries are supported by android, then try copying the main folder of the library in the data folder of your sketch. You can find the folder for the various libraries in the "libraries" folder which will be located inside the directory where all your sketches are stored.

Also try updating your sdk by clicking `Android >> SDK Updater` in your processing IDE.

One other solution could be updating using the sdk manager. If you are in windows, you can generally find the sdk manager in `C:\users\username\appdata\local\android\sdk\tools\bin` open this in cmd and then type `sdkmanager --update` to update.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it was the processing video library that messed things up. Easy enough fix seeing it only does 2 or 3 things in the program. I've been stuck on this for weeks.

Comment: while doing some random stuff, I found that you can make the video library work on android mode by doing this:



1) in your sketchbook, go to libraries and copy the video folder
2) back from your sketchbook go to modes -> AndroidMode -> libraries
3) paste the video folder here
try running your code now and hopefully you should not get any error